# Constructor of class derived from QCustomPlot

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I have tried deriving from QCustomPlot class, and then promoted a widget to that particular class but when buiding it shows the following error.
Graphytti/myqcustomplot.cpp:2: error: undefined reference to `vtable for MyQCustomPlot'
:-1: error: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Below is the contents of myqcustomplot.h file

```
#ifndef MYQCUSTOMPLOT_H
#define MYQCUSTOMPLOT_H
#include "qcustomplot.h"
#include<QPoint>
class MyQCustomPlot:public QCustomPlot{

    Q_OBJECT
    QPoint cursor_pos;
    public:
    explicit MyQCustomPlot(QWidget *parent=0);
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent * event);
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event);
    void paintCoordinate();


};

#endif // MYQCUSTOMPLOT_H
```

Below is the contents of my qcustomplot.cpp file

```
    #include "myqcustomplot.h"
MyQCustomPlot::MyQCustomPlot(QWidget *parent): QCustomPlot(parent)
 {
    ;
}

void MyQCustomPlot::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent * event)
{
    cursor_pos = event->pos();
    replot();
    QCustomPlot::mouseMoveEvent(event);
}


void MyQCustomPlot::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QCustomPlot::paintEvent(event);
    paintCoordinate();
}

void MyQCustomPlot::paintCoordinate()
{
    /*double price = getPrice(cursor_pos);
    int y = yAxis->coordToPixel(price);*/
    int y=0;
    QPainter painter(this);

    painter.drawLine(QPoint(50, y), QPoint(width(), y));
    painter.drawLine(cursor_pos, QPoint(cursor_pos.x(), y));

    //painter.drawText(QPoint(0, y), QString::number(price));
    //painter.drawText(cursor_pos, timestamp);
}
```

After some searching , I realised that probably my constructor is not well defined or there is some possible linking problem.

I am new to Qt development and would like assistance in this matter.

**PROBLEM SOLVED**
I don't know exactly what was the problem .I deleted the two files and added them again using QtCreator. There was no issue after building this time. Probably a MOC issue and hence upvoting that answer.

Comment: Could you include your .pro file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you create a `Q_OBJECT` class, you should run `qmake` to generate required moc cpp files.

```
Build -> Run qmake
```